# The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula

I'm working on a custom formula but I'm getting a syntax error and I can't figure out the error. Essentially what I'm trying to do is a sign a value to a custom field based on amount? Thank you for your help in advance for your help. We want to be able to show $0 if $0 is entered. My formula is below:

```
IF(X > $1,000, "$5",
IF(X > $500, "$4",
IF(X > $100,"$3",
IF(X > $10, "$2",
IF(X > $1,"$1",
IF(X > $0,"$0", Null)))))
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, your formula will be like this:

```
IF(X > $1,000, "$5",
      IF(X > $500, "$4",
          IF(X > $100,000,"$3",
              IF(X > $10, "$2",
                  IF(X > $1,"$1",
                     IF(X < $1,"$0", Null)
                  )
                )
           )
       )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you Santanu, I can see your formula makes sense however after adjustment I'm getting a " Field $1 does not exist. Check spelling." error now.

Comment: remove entire formula and try to add one by one condition in the formula

Comment: @Xperez -- is X a currency field? if yes, remove the formatting from the comparands - also, shouldn't the third if be $100; what if x = $1 ?